# what went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project 'razerpay_flutter'

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, flutter-packages

im using this package in my project ,
so when i got the error i commented the entire code related to razerpay but the second time i got this error 'what went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project 'sqflite'' ,the thing is im not using the package sqflite in my project.
i can't run my project,

here is the error

Launching lib\main.dart on SM M307F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':razorpay_flutter'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\BFLY\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\razorpay_flutter-1.3.4\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':razorpay_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':fluttertoast'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':package_info_plus'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':razorpay_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

i did flutter clean ,get , upgrade ,almost everything

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.